# How to redirect from a.html page to login.jsp page if try to browse a.html without login in login.jsp page

Tags: html

I'm doing 1 web-system, where login page is login.jsp but other functional page in .html format (suppose: a.html) where I use javascript to do function also. Suppose if without login try to browse a.html page it will auto redirect to login.jsp page. But how to do it, I don’t know. please help me to get the solution please.I'm new in programming.

Comment: You may want to check for a cookie but this is not good. If a.html would be a jsp, you could check for a variable in session then proceed or redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use hidden fields to do what you want, it would not be appropriate because they are not safe. Instead use jsp sessions. Make all your files jsp file and in login.jsp, store a variable to session object and check that variable in the other pages to see whether user has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

try to make a function which check the login. Call this function on each pageload. When the user is not logged in you can redirect to the login site.

Regards HomePageCreator